# Preventing the default action only for a left swipe/right swipe event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `event.preventDefault` but after some checks, I want the event to continue.

For eg, For the

> touchmove

event I am using `event.preventDefault()` as I don't want the browser to scroll horizontally, but after determining the direction of swipe, if the direction turns out to be up/down, whatever event i have prevented, i want to nullify the effect. Is that possible?

My scenario

This is my html

```
<div id="teazer" class="globalTeaser"  ontouchcancel="touchCancel(event);" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);" ontouchend="touchEnd(event,'gTeaser');" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'teazer');">
```

This is my js after removing the irrelevant part

> 

```
function touchMove(event) {
        if(fingerCount==1){
            event.preventDefault();
               if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {
                               curX = event.touches[0].pageX;
                                curY = event.touches[0].pageY;
               } 
               else {
                                touchCancel(event);
                    }
        }else {
            touchCancel(event);
            alert("hi");
}

}

function touchEnd(event,eventType) {

                    //I get the swipe direction here,after some calculations
                    //I get the directions fine,now 
                    //if the swipe direction is up/down whatever event i have prevented in touch move I need to nullify

}
```

Please note, if anyone is gonna suggest window.scrollBy, for some reason its not working for me. Any other solutions I am happy to try.

Comment: Do check first, than `preventDefault` if needed only.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @john: i will get the swipe direction only after the "touchend" event. I am preventing the default action in "touchmove" event. So your solution is not correct.

Comment: @Satpal: I will put the relevant parts and explain.

Comment: can you put a check around event.preventDefault()  maybe an if statement to check if something is set etc.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My touchMove() function has been rewritten as follows

```js
function touchMove(event) {
  if (event.touches.length == 1) {
    curX = event.touches[0].pageX;
    curY = event.touches[0].pageY;
    
    if (Math.abs((curX - startX)) > 10) {
      //default acion is prevented only if the 
      //finger count is one and change in  
      //x coordinatesis greater than 10 px                                   
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  } 
  else {
    touchCancel(event);
  }
}
```

This code will make sure of two things

1)Pinch to zoom is not affected

2)default action for vertical swipe is not affected

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your code behaves exactly, but this is the general principle:

```
// Keep a reference for last point both events can access
var start;

$( 'body' ).on( {
  // On start, assign the event data to start
  touchstart : function touchStart( touchstartEvent ){
    start = touchstartEvent.touches[ 0 ];
  },
  touchmove  : function touchMove( touchmoveEvent ){
    // The difference between both events positions
    var delta = {};
    // The end event's position
    var end   = touchmoveEvent.touches[ 0 ];

    // Calculate the offset compared to start for this move event
    delata.pageX = start.pageX - end.pageX;
    delata.pageY = start.pageY - end.pageY;

    // If pageX is less than or greater than 0, it means there has been horizontal movement,
    // and this if condition will pass
    if( delta.pageX ){
      touchmoveEvent.preventDefault();
    }
  }
} );
```

This isn't perfect, because in practice it's very difficult to create a perfect downward or upward swipe — my finger might move a couple of pixels left or right even if the main movement is downwards. But then you have the problem of preventing horizontal motion but not vertical! In any case, the general principal for testing different properties of a touch event and only preventing default in certain conditions is illustrated.

Comment: hey thanks, but will the end coordinates be generated on the touch move event itself? Shouldn't we wait till touchend?

Comment: Sorry your solution is right needs some changes though, but thanks you made a park in my mind. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Livejava may be — to be honest I've always shied away from doing anything this intrusive with touch events. If I were you I'd use a touch event library like [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/), whereby you could then simply execute `Hammer( document.body ).on( 'swipeleft swiperight', function( e ){ e.preventDefault() } )`

Comment: ha ha... I saw many plugins, but our quality guys will always find some trouble if we use any plugins. Inorder to avoid last minute fights, digging deep with the touch events. Lemme check hammer.js too.

Comment: Don't understand the value of putting. `Math.abs` in there. If there were any problems regarding it not being a real number, they would have occurred earlier during subtraction from start point. But because these are extracted directly from read-only native touch events' numeric properties, it shouldn't need it then either.

Comment: i added a threshold value of 10 px, `if( delta.pageX>10 )` as you said user may not swipe in exactly one direction. I used `Math.abs` so that the result will always be positive.

Comment: Aha! Now I understand — think you should add that as an addendum to your question (because this was your idea, not mine). Excellent thinking. Hope this works well!